# Passing location and pageContext from page to child components in Gatsby

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

My page layout for a Gatsby site looks like this.

```
const Container = ({location, children, pageContext}) => {
  return (
    <>
      <Header location={location} />
      <Breadcrumbs pageContext={pageContext} />
      {children}
      <Footer />
    </>
  )
}
```

I need to pass `location` and `pageContext` from the page to the child components. I have tried to add `location` and `pageContext` to the `DataProvider` like this:

```
export const DataContext = React.createContext();

const DataProvider = ({ children, location, pageContext }) => {
  return (
    <DataContext.Provider value={{
      location,
      pageContext
    }}>
      {children}
    </DataContext.Provider>
  )
};

export default DataContext
export { DataProvider }
```

Then I use `DataProvider` in `gatsby-ssr.js` and `gatsby-browser.js` like this:

```
export const wrapRootElement = ({ element }) => (
  <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
    <DataProvider>
      {element}
    </DataProvider>
  </ThemeProvider>
);
```

In the child component:

```
const HeaderLinks = () => {
  return (
    <DataContext.Consumer>
      {
        context => (
          <Menu
            theme="light"
            mode="horizontal"
            selectedKeys={[context.location.pathname]}
          >
            <Menu.Item key={key}>
              <Link to={url}>{name}</Link>
            </Menu.Item>
          </Menu>
        )
      }
    </DataContext.Consumer>
  )
}
```

But it doesn't seem to work, as it is not getting updated when I move to another page. (I also have `wrapPageElement` with `Container`, may be that's reasons.)

How can I pass `location` and `pageContext` to the child components? Is it better to use React Context or simply pass them as props? If I should use React Context, how can I correct my code to make it work?

Comment: For the second case how do you use dataprovider

Comment: I would just pass them as props TBH. Why do you need context here? See [Before You use context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#before-you-use-context)

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri I've updated my question and added the code https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62057441/revisions

Comment: @RobinMétral This is a simplified example. My `Header` has `HeaderLinks` which actually need to use the `location`. So I end up passing the same props down from one component to another.

Comment: @jupiteror personally, I would still use props (this is my opinion on "Is it better to use React Context or simply pass them as props?" in your question). You state is simple and 2-3 levels of nesting is fine for props. Context makes your implementation more complex, I would keep it simple unless you need to pass down a theme or complex state.

Comment: @RobinMétral Ok, thank you very much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of using `wrapRootElement` to use `ContexProvider` you can make use of `wrapPageElement` where you can get the page props and pass them on to the DataProvider. This will make sure that pageContext and location change on each page

```
export const wrapRootElement = ({ element }) => (
  <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      {element}
  </ThemeProvider>
);

export const wrapPageElement = ({ element, props }) => (
  <DataProvider value={props}>
      {element}
  </DataProvider>
);
```

---

```
export const DataContext = React.createContext();

const DataProvider = ({ children, value }) => {
  const {location, pageContext} = value;
  return (
    <DataContext.Provider value={{
      location,
      pageContext
    }}>
      {children}
    </DataContext.Provider>
  )
};

export default DataContext
export { DataProvider }
```

Comment: Doesn't it contradict Gatsby docs https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/browser-apis/#wrapRootElement? They say: for setting Provider components, use `wrapRootElement`.

Comment: Agreed but what you want to achieve needs context acessible within the page only and not across pages

Comment: I ended up using `useLocation` from @reach/router to return location in child components. And I simply pass `pageContext` as a prop to `<Breadcrumbs />`, as it is used only once and is not passed down to any child components.

Comment: But did the above solution not work. Because if at all you need to use it in other components in future your solution isn't perfect

Comment: Why do you think it's not perfect?

Comment: Because say you want to pass pageContext to some other component and may a deep nested one, you will have to pass this prop at each level

Answer (score 2):

I ended up using `useLocation` from `@reach/router` to return location in child components. And I simply pass `pageContext` as a prop to `<Breadcrumbs />`, as it is used only once and is not passed down to any child components.